# How to stay at the same page if BindingResult has errors in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, model-view-controller, view, controller

I would like to stay at the same page with the filled form with "wrong" data, if binding result has errors. I have this code, but i got npe and null object "employeeTripOrder". What i do wrong? I can't use the RedirectAttributes cause i have old spring version.

```
   @RequestMapping("/editEmployeeTripOrder")
        public String editEmployeeTripOrder(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            @RequestParam("trip_cards") String tripCards,
                                            @RequestParam("dependenceTypes") String dependenceType,
                                            @RequestParam("dependenceOrderIds") String dependenceOrderId,
                                            @Valid @ModelAttribute("trip_order") EmployeeTripOrder employeeTripOrder,
                                            BindingResult bindingResult,
                                            ModelMap modelMap) throws Exception {
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
     modelMap.addAttribute("trip_cards", tripCards);
                modelMap.addAttribute("dependenceTypes", dependenceType);
                modelMap.addAttribute("dependenceOrderIds", dependenceOrderId);
    
    
                modelMap.addAttribute("trip_order",employeeTripOrder);
    
    return "redirect:/editEmployeeTripOrder";}
//***    }
```

Comment: what is your problem, get a null value for `employeeTripOrder` or redirection not work properly ?

Comment: The second one, i got null values on employeeTripOrder

Comment: please share the source relevant to front end